# la propiedad SelectCommand.Connection no se ha inicializado. MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, signalr

Resulta que estoy trabajando con SignalR, en donde en la vista html hago la siguiente solicitud al cliente:

```
 var myHub = $.connection.myHub;
        var direccionWeb = $("#direccionWeb").val().toString();
        $.connection.hub.url = direccionWeb + "/signalr";
        $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
            myHub.server.broadcastMessageToPrinterReportTicket(global_venta, global_mesa, nombregarzon, idgrupo, grupo);

        }).fail(function (error) {
            console.error(error);
        });
```

En el archivo Hub tengo los siguiente:

```
public void BroadcastMessageToPrinterReportTicket(String global_venta,String global_mesa,String nombregarzon,String idgrupo, String grupo)
    {
        string nombreImpresora = grupo;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        string sql = "SELECT " +
            "cantidad," +
            "detalle " +
            "FROM producto " +                
            "WHERE venta=@global_venta AND venta>0 AND menu.grupo=@idgrupo AND comandasd.pedido=0";
        conexion.conectar(); 

        using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conexion.con))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@global_venta", global_venta);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idgrupo", idgrupo);
            using (MySqlDataAdapter reader = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
            {
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter(command))
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        conexion.cerrar();


        Clients.All.imprimeReport(datos, ........);
    }
```

El archivo que contiene la clase de conección es el siguiente:

```
public void conectar()
    {
        try
        {
            string ip = HttpContext.Current.Session["ip"].ToString();
            string db = HttpContext.Current.Session["db"].ToString();
            string user = HttpContext.Current.Session["user"].ToString();
            string pass = HttpContext.Current.Session["pass"].ToString();

            con = new MySqlConnection("server=" + ip + ";user id=" + user + ";password=" + pass + ";database=" + db + ";port=3306;Allow User Variables=true"); 
            con.Open();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
```

Pero cuando intento agregar datos al DataTable, es decir en la linea donde dice  sda.Fill(dt), me aparece el siguiente error:
**la propiedad SelectCommand.Connection no se ha inicializado.**

Lo extraño que cuando uso está misma función declarada en el controller, funciona correctamente. Lo que deseo es poder obtener un datatable con los parámetros que recibe BroadcastMessageToPrinterReportTicket y enviarlo al cliente.

Si alguien supiera como corregir el error, o alguna ayuda, se le agradecería.

Saludos

Comment: Por favor nunca pongas un bloque `catch` vacío en tu código como lo haces en tu método `conectar`, a menos que tengas una excelente razón para ello. Tal vez estás recibiendo un error en este método, y por supuesto no estás recibiendo el error, y ahora parece que hay un misterio. Adicionalmente, por favor evita el patrón peligroso (sobre todo en ASP.NET) de mantener una conexión en una variable global. Si quieres centralizar el código para crear la conexión, ok, pero no mantengas una referencia allí. Mas bien usa un bloque `using` donde lo necesitas, tal como lo haces con `SqlCommand`.

Comment: @sstan
Descubrí la causa del error, es que al usar el archivo Hub de signalR, las variables de session se hacen null, e incluso si declaro alguna variable de session en el HUB, no me deja porque dice error de codigo. Interesante lo que dices de haber un patron peligros, en que sentido lo dices??? y permitiría el using, que se ganaría?

Comment: Imagina que 2 usuarios intentan ejecutar el mismo código al mismo tiempo. Ambos estarían tratando de trabajar con la misma conexión. Esto puede causar problemas inesperados, incluyendo resultados raros, tal vez un error, tal vez puede hacer que uno cierre la conexión antes que el otro haya terminado de usarlo, etc... Por eso es importante que cada usuario trabaje con su propia conexión, no una conexión compartida como lo tienes.